# 60-year old dad passes out after 1/2 an hour of badminton

Tags: badminton

My dad is 60 years old. I have never played any kind of sports for 30 years. 
However, he's working with geography and sometimes (maybe a week per month) he has to hike in the jungle as a part of his job.

Recently, a heart doctor prescribed medication for him. He now takes a heart pill every morning.

Today, he told me he wants to play badminton with me. This is the 1st time he played sports. So we played for 30 minutes. Then suddenly he felt tired and he sat down. Then, right at that time, I saw he fell asleep. I tried to call him but he didn't wake up. So I rushed out and call an ambulance, but my dad suddenly woke up.

He just passed out for 5 minutes. He told me that his doctor said he should do the walking exercise only.

My question is that "Is badminton too much for 60-year old person?"

And "What should I do now?"

- Tell him to stop playing badminton
- Tell him to do the walking exercise only

I am very worried for him. I thought he could have a stroke. I thought since he took the heart pills everyday, that could help him recover.

Comment: Medical related questions are off-topic.

Comment: As Jacob says, this is off-topic. But if a trained medical professional says X, I'd suggest that X is probably a good idea.